# Unable to get matching Electron symbols for minidump file

Tags: electron, crash-reports, google-breakpad

I'm trying to analyze an Electron crash. I've installed Electron v2.0.0. I've downloaded the corresponding symbol zip file. I've built Breakpad, which includes the `minidump_stackwalk` tool. When I now execute:

```
minidump_stackwalk <breakpad_minidump_file> <sym_path>
```

I'm getting a lot of output which still contains messages like "WARNING: No symbols ...", even though I can see that minidum_stackwalk searches at right place.

What am I doing wrong?